# Avoid highlighting all rows and columns with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I am using the following piece of jQuery for my table in Twitter Bootstrap:

```
$('td').mouseover(function () {
   $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#EAD575');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '#EAD575');
});
$('td').mouseleave(function () {
   $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '');
});
```

I found this piece of code on a site and I must admit, this works perfectly...

...however is it possible to tweak it a bit, so it doesn't target the selected row and/or column either.

For example ignore the row/column with an ID called 'nohover'

Is this possible? The reason for this, is that I have about 3 or 4 merged rows which shouldn't be highlighted, because it will look "weird".

Anyone knows if this is possible, if so; how?

Comment: You can use :not(selector). Check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().not('.nohover')` should do the trick

```
$('td').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).siblings().not('.nohover').css('background-color', '#EAD575');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').not('.nohover').css('background-color', '#EAD575');
});
$('td').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '');
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').not('.nohover').css('background-color', '');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cd54pqdx/1/

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to do this is to rely on external CSS a bit more. Instead of changing the background-color with inline CSS, you can add a CSS class with that background color. Just make sure that your .no-hover class has a background-color set to transparent (or whatever the default background color is for your table cells).

Since CSS cascades, you can place the .no-hover class below your new class in the stylesheet and the no-hover class will take precedence.

The code would change from

```
$('td').mouseover(function () {
   $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#EAD575');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '#EAD575');
});
$('td').mouseleave(function () {
   $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').css('background-color', '');
});
```

to

```
$('td').mouseover(function () {
   $(this).siblings().addClass('active-hover');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').addClass('active-hover');
});
$('td').mouseleave(function () {
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active-hover');
   var ind = $(this).index();
   $('td:nth-child(' + (ind + 1) + ')').removeClass('active-hover');
});
```

(Change active-hover to whatever you decide you hover class to be named)

I would avoid using the CSS3 :not selector because it is not supported in <=IE8